# Dart: How to create a public, final object that is not a passed-in parameter

Tags: dart

As a recent convert from the land of duck typing, I'm asking this question because I suspect others may have found themselves in this corner of thought as well. I want `baz` to be both final and public. Can I do that? If so, how?

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  Baz baz;

  Foo({this.bar}) {
    baz = _someFunction(bar);
  }

  Baz _someFunction(Bar bar) {
    ...
    return baz;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can only do that with null-safety enabled and the `late` keyword. This is not possible in earlier versions of dart as final variables are not allowed to be changed.

Comment: I should have more specifically said, public and *immutable* (by any means), something like Ruby's `.freeze` (different world, I know). Is there anything like that, or is the `late` keyword *the* way?

Comment: I meant *add* the `late` keyword. Don't remove `final`.

Comment: A `late final Baz baz;` will have a public setter, visible in the interface and possibly the documentation (if you document). If you don't want that (and you likely don't), either give the variable an initializer, or make it private and have a public getter to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Christopher Moore noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66321189/dart-how-to-create-a-public-final-object-that-is-not-a-passed-in-parameter#comment117250400_66321189), if Dart's null-safety features are enabled, you can use the [`late` keyword to initialize `final` members](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-final-variables):

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  late final Baz baz;

  Foo({this.bar}) {
    baz = _someFunction(bar);
  }
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, even without null-safety, if you can make `_someFunction` not be an instance method on `Foo` you could use a `factory` constructor as an intermediary:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  final Baz baz;

  Foo._(this.bar, this.baz);

  factory Foo({Bar bar}) {
    return Foo._(bar, _someFunction(bar));
  }

  ...
}
```

Also, be aware that the `final` keyword prevents the field from referring to a different object, but it does not make that object immutable.

Answer (score 0):

If `_someFunction` is static, or can be made static, then you can call it in the initializer list:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  final Baz baz;
  Foo(this.bar) : baz = _someFunction(bar);
  static Baz _someFunction(Bar bar) { ... }
}
```

If the computation is more complicated than what a single function can do, perhaps computing multiple values at the same time, then you can use a factory constructor to compute, and a private generative constructor to construct:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar; 
  final Baz baz;
  factory Foo(Bar bar) {
    // long complex computation.
    return Foo._(bar, baz);
  }
  Foo._(this.bar, this.baz);
}
```

If you can delay the computation until `baz` is first read, then you can use a late variable with initializer:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  late final Baz baz = _someFunction(bar);
  Foo(this.bar);
  Baz _someFunction(Bar bar) { ... }
}
```

That still ensures that `baz` has no setter.
(You can even add a read of `baz` in the constructor, to ensure that it's computed early. Sligthly confusing to see a constructor body of `{ baz; }`, but it works.

Otherwise, I'd probably make `baz` a getter backed by a private field, and then do whatever makes most sense with that field:

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  Baz? _baz;
  Baz get baz => _baz!;
  Foo(this.bar) {
    _baz = _someFunction(bar);
  }
  Baz _someFunction(Bar bar) { ... }
}
```

or

```dart
class Foo {
  final Bar bar;
  late final Baz? _baz;
  Baz get baz => _baz!;
  Foo(this.bar) {
    _baz = _someFunction(bar);
  }
  Baz _someFunction(Bar bar) { ... }
}
```

I would *avoid* a public late final variable with no initializer.
Such a variable has a *public setter*. It's visible in the API, and someone might feel inclined to call it (it'll throw because you already initialized it once, but it's still messy).

That only matters if it's a public API. For an internal API, ... do whatever. If anyone disagrees, they can change the code anyway.